# Local Laravel error 404 with duplicated URL redirection

Tags: php, laravel, apache, error-handling

Currently trying to set up a Laravel project on my local PC.I added the hostname ***127.0.0.1 localhost-smt*** to the Windows hostfile and edited my Apache httpd-vhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1"
     <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 
<VirtualHost *:80>  
    ServerName localhost-smt  
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/smt/public"  
    ErrorLog "logs/testseite-error.log"  
    CustomLog "logs/testseite-access.log" common  
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/project1/smt/">  
    AllowOverride All  
    Allow from All  
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

My Apache httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
```

Each time I connect to localhost-smt/home I am receiving a double URL like ***http://localhost-smt/127.0.0.1/home***. Further more if I navigate from localhost to the public folder and add ***/home*** i receive the following URL ***http://localhost/smt/public/127.0.0.1/smt/public/home***.

I tried a lot of different solutions, but none of them worked so far. I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this riddle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this using .conf files but the way I used to achieve this when I used Xampp was as follows, doing it this way will obviously mean undoing anything you have done to the default behaviour of Xampp relating to the .conf files you have edited.

1. Add the name resolution to your hosts file

> `127.0.0.1    dev.projectName`

2. Add the following .htaccess file into the root of your projects directory (typically "C:/xampp/htdocs")

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev.projectName$
> RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ projectName/$1 [L]
> ```

3. add the following .htaccess file to the root of your project (typically "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectName")

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /dev.projectName/
>
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
>
> RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
> ```

4. Add the following .htaccess file into your public directory (typically "C:/xampp/htdocs/projectName/public")

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /dev.projectName/public/
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
> ```

5. this can be viewed by going to `http:\\dev.projectName`

I know it is a long-winded way of doing it but it was the only solution I could find at the time and it worked for me.

It does become a ball-ache having to do this every time you create a new project which is one of the reasons I switched to docker which in my opinion is a much better solution anyway,

Comment: I added all the .htaccess-files but receiving a internal server error. I will try to reset XAMPP and check if it works. Thank you for the answer neverless